# How to make toggleClass changes persist as visitor moves between pages?

Tags: javascript, jquery, local-storage, session-state

Potential coding-efficiency issues aside, I put together a jQuery function for a toggle button of mine. When clicking the toggle on and off, the site applies various CSS classes and styles for a dark mode. This works extremely well:

```
$(function() {
   $(".slider.round").click(function() {
     $("#canvas-wrapper").toggleClass("dark-canvas");
     $("#page-body-wrapper p").toggleClass("dark-body-text");
     $("h2, h3, .summary-title a, .summary-read-more-link, .summary-excerpt a, #block-yui_3_17_2_32_1456852631790_12688 a").toggleClass("dark-headings-links");
     $("#block-yui_3_17_2_2_1457035305182_118918 h2").toggleClass("dark-intro");
     $(".summary-item").toggleClass("dark-summary");
     $(".summary-excerpt strong, #sidebar-one h2").toggleClass("dark-excerpt-sidebar");
     $("#sidebar-one, .sqs-col-1").toggleClass("dark-sidebar");
     $(".summary-metadata-item a, .summary-metadata-item--date").toggleClass("dark-metadata");
   });
});
```

However, there's one big problem. Say a visitor toggles on dark mode, changing the appearance accordingly. When they reload the page or move between pages, this state resets itself every time. This is jarring when a user is navigating a dark interface, then is suddenly presented with a white-dominated design.

What could I add to this function to allow those `toggleClass` states to persist from page to page? Another user pointed me towards `localStorage` and `sessionStorage`. Unfortunately, I'm still quite a novice at jQuery and lack the knowledge to put something intricate together - much less make sense of related terminology.

Could anybody please lend a hand with this? It would be a huge help and step forward!

Thanks a million guys, you're rockstars :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I recommend that you simplify your code right in the CSS file. It's absolutely unnecessary for you to be adding a gazillion classes to each and every element using JavaScript.

Instead, you can work with one class, let's call it "mode--dark", and we'll be adding it to the body.

In your CSS, this class can look like this:

```
.mode--dark #canvas-wrapper {
 // your styles
}

.mode--dark #page-body-wrapper p {
 // your styles
}


//--------------------> right after body script start (this should go right after <body> tag
function getMode() {
    // let's check whether key "mode" exists in our localStorage and if so return true, false otherwise
    return localStorage.getItem('mode') == 'true' ? true : false;
}

var body = document.querySelector('body'),
      modeClass = 'mode--dark',
      switchClass = 'js-switch'; // add any class name to your input for switching between themes and retype it here


if (getMode()) {
    body.classList.add(modeClass);
}

document.addEventListener('change', function (e) {
    var target = e.target;

    if (target.className.indexOf(switchClass) > -1) {
        if(!getMode()) {
            body.classList.add(modeClass);
            // set dark mode to true
            localStorage.setItem('mode', true);
        } else {
            body.classList.remove(modeClass);
            // set dark mode to false
            localStorage.setItem('mode', false);
        }
    }
});

//--------------------> right after body script end

//--------------------> this can be put anywhere start
document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', function (e) {
    var switchInput = document.querySelector('.' + switchClass);

    if(getMode()) {
        switchInput.checked = true;
    }
});
//--------------------> this can be put anywhere end
```

Comment: Hey thanks! Haha I figured things weren't exactly optimal. I was piecing things together as a proof of concept then figured I'd slim things down majorly as needed.

I'll redo things and test, then get back to you about this.

Comment: Hi, no problem. Hopefully, my answer turned out to be useful. Basically anything can be refactored, and thus improved.

Comment: Working great! Thanks a ton. Saves its state for new sessions too, which is awesome. There's only one small problem: when I click the slider initially, it slides to the right to activate. That's all good. 

However, visiting subsequent pages resets that slider position to inactive, even though dark mode persists. If I click this toggle again to "activate" it, the page returns to the light theme. This creates a weird state where toggle functionality reverses. Any ideas on this?

My site for reference: https://tylercharboneau.com

Thanks again!

Comment: Also, I seem to be getting flashes of the default white UI before all styles are fully applied - when moving from page to page.

Comment: Hi, as for the flashing... it would be best to do the class change through session/cookies on the back-end.  

If we can't achieve that, we'll need to tweak the code a bit. 

The input gets reversed because we don't make sure that it's checked oncewe have switched to the dark mode. 

 if (getMode()) {
        $body.addClass('mode--dark');
        // make the input active
       // $('INPUT_CLASS').prop('checked', true);
    }

Comment: I'll get back to you in the afternoon once I've finished at work.

Comment: I have just edited the previous answer. This should work much smoother.

Comment: Thanks for the update! Eager to test things out. Two quick questions: is placing the scripts in the footer too late in the DOM? I work within a WYSIWYG editor, so any post-body jQuery must be placed in code blocks and subsequently hidden. Also, is `js-switch` a stand-in for my toggle-button class (i.e. `slider-round`)?

Comment: It might be too late but I recommend that you try it out. The thing is that we need to add the class "mode--dark" to body as soon as possible, this is the only way we can supress the unwated effect, which is flashing.  The `js-switch` class is intended to be used for the input itself which is next to `<span class="slider round">`

Comment: Seems to be working well now! Had to put it in the footer unfortunately, which may nullify the benefits. Given that fact, how does performance with this function stack up with our first iteration? Testing seems to reveal the rendering is slightly better. EDIT: My dark toggle, for the time being, is in the footer.

Comment: What do you mean by "first iteration"? Do you mean first page loading, or "first click", or something totally different? None of the aforementioned cases is too heavy for a browser I would say. Perhaps, the event listener for "change", which is attached to the whole document where we are only checking for a change but only work with our input is not ideal. It's just because the script was meant to be at the very top to ensure that we attach the class `"mode--dark"` to body as soon as possible.

Comment: Sorry about that! I meant the first version of your function before updating your answer (if you can recall). I think I'm a little handcuffed at the moment since my toggle in the footer. The scripts didn't work until I added them into the footer, presumably after the toggle.

Comment: Ahh, I see. Well, the first version did basically the same thing as this piece of code. The main difference was that we were using jQuery instead. Because jQuery is quite heavy, and we didn't want to wait for it, I figured it would be better to use plain JavaScript. The core functionality of this little "app" is very simple, and we don't need to use methods such as "toggleClass". This should be faster than the previous answer since we don't use any framework. We work with built-in stuff directly. The main advantage of this is -- **we don't need to wait for jQuery to be loaded.**

Answer (score 1):

The issue you're having is a symptom of a lack of separation between your data layer and your view layer. Instead of directly changing your html when the user clicks the toggle, you want to update your data layer, then rerender your view. Ideally, you'd be using some kind of javascript templating to render your html, like lodash's `template` function, or a framework like angular/react. However, I've kept the example just using jquery. The flow would look something like this:

Initial page load:
`Data` -> `View`

Toggle:
`Update Data` -> `Rerender View`

So you keep track of your dark mode in a variable, then update your html when it changes:

```
var localStorageKey = 'appState';
var appState;

function loadState() {
    const json = localStorage[localStorageKey];

    if (json) appState = JSON.parse(json);
    else appState = {};
}

function saveState() {
    localStorage[localStorageKey] = JSON.stringify(appState);
}

function render() {
    $('body').toggleClass('mode--dark', state.isDarkMode);
}

loadState();
render();

$('.darkModeToggle').click(function() {
    appState.isDarkMode = !appState.isDarkMode;
    saveState();
    render();
});
```

Comment: Hey there, doesn't seem to be doing anything unfortunately. Where should this be placed, ideally?

Comment: You'll need to update the selectors to work with your page. Also, javascript can only work on stuff that's already loaded, so the usual place to put scripts that modify the DOM is at the end of your body tag. However, you'll still get a flash of "light mode" before the script has a chance to run. The only way to fix that is to render your html using javascript, or do server-side templating.

Comment: Gotcha. Yeah my dark mode class is `.mode--dark`, so that looks to be fine. I updated `.darkModeToggle` - the class is `.slider.round`, should that denoted as such or as `slider round`? Does anything else need to be changed there? Also I'm unfortunately handcuffed by Squarespace's implementation here, so rendering is a bit out of my hands. Thanks!

Comment: Gotcha, makes sense with the rendering. Actually, come to think of it, you could move everything except the click listener into a script up in the head, because your body tag is still guaranteed to be there. However, your click listener code needs to run after the toggle switch html has been loaded. For your slider, I'd recommend giving it a specific class name, because with something as generic as `.slider.round`, it'll break if you add another slider to the page.

Comment: Good deal! I'll reposition and retest. Good suggestion also. Silly question, but does the the click function begin at `$('darkModeToggle')`? I'm a little more accustomed to jQuery syntax, so I wasn't sure if `loadState` or `render` were part of that.

Comment: Ah, sorry, I used an arrow function, which looks like `(argument1, argument2) => { // function body }`. It's a normal function that has the value of `this` bound to it. However, it's not compatible with IE, so you wouldn't want to use it unless you're using build tools that recompile it to be compatible. I'll update my answer to use a normal function.